Candel High Crossover EMA Within a Range - UnExpected Results
RSI DIVERGENCE - INDICATOR
Concept:
It checks for the lowest low while the RSI is oversold and stores it when the market leaves the oversold condition.If there's a second low that is lower than the first low, with a higher RSI value, and within a maximum distance, it checks for a crossover of the highest price between the two lows and the EMA.If the conditions for bullish divergence are met, it sets the bullishDivergence flag to true and draws a line indicating the divergence.
Our Requirements as Images :
What I Try to Create
Compiler Warning :
Warning at 41:34 The function 'ta.highest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
Warning at 42:8 The function 'ta.crossover' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this sco
pe.
Result on Chart :
Result
Candel High Crossover EMA Within a Range But it's Not Respect the condition & unexpected results.
// @version=5
indicator("Live RSI Divergence with SMA Condition", overlay=true)

// Get user input

int i_MaxDistance       = input.int(title="Max Bar Distance", defval=100)
int i_RSI_Length        = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=13, minval=1)
float i_RSI_Overbought  = input.float(title="RSI Overbought", defval=70.0)
float i_RSI_Oversold    = input.float(title="RSI Oversold", defval=30.0)
int emaLength           = input.int(title="EMA Length", defval=50, minval=1)


// Get RSI value

rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, i_RSI_Length)
emavalue = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

// --------- BULLISH DIVERGENCE --------- //

var float checkFirstLow     = na
var float initialLowPrice   = na
var float initialLowRSI     = na
var int initialLowIndex     = na
bool bullishDivergence      = false
float swingLowRSI           = ta.lowest(rsiValue, 5)

// Save lowest low while RSI is oversold, and store it when market leaves OS condition

if (rsiValue < i_RSI_Oversold or rsiValue[1] < i_RSI_Oversold)
    if not na(initialLowPrice)
        initialLowPrice := na
    if na(checkFirstLow) or low < checkFirstLow
        checkFirstLow := low
        initialLowIndex := bar_index
        initialLowRSI := swingLowRSI
else
    // RSI is no longer OS, save lowest price during OS condition and reset temporary low

    if not na(checkFirstLow)
        initialLowPrice := checkFirstLow
    checkFirstLow := na

// Check for a second low that is lower than the first, and with a higher RSI value, and within our max distance

if low < initialLowPrice and swingLowRSI > initialLowRSI and bar_index - initialLowIndex <= i_MaxDistance
    float highestPriceBetween =  ta.highest(high, bar_index - initialLowIndex)
    if ta.crossover(highestPriceBetween,emavalue)
        bullishDivergence := true
        line.new(initialLowIndex, initialLowPrice, bar_index, low, color=color.yellow, width=2)
        initialLowPrice := na

plot(emavalue,linewidth = 2)


